# Group law of elliptic curve under transformation

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

For example, elliptic curve $E:y^2＝x^3-x$ can be transformed
to move the identity element to the origin, $(z,w)=(0,0)$, we do the change of coordinates $z=-x/y$, $w=-1/y$. The equation of this curve then becomes
$w=z^3+zw^2\quad$

My question is
; Does E':$w=z^3+zw^2 $have group structure, just like ' take two points from $E'$,and line through those points intersects at $E'$ , and connect the point with $（0,0）∈（z,w）$, then the line intersects with $E'$ again, and this is the sum of first two points' ?

The graph of $w=z^3+zw^2\quad$seems completely different in affine plane from usual $y^2＝x^3-x$, so I'm suspicious. But maybe we can say the group structure above holds because they are both same Weierstrass from in projective plane, so is isomorphic to Picard group of $E$.

Comment: If you read the definition of the group law on an elliptic curve in chapter III of silverman (specifically "Composition Law 2.1") you'll note that no reference is made to $E$ being in Weierstrass form. It is a good exercise to derive the group law on some other families of smooth cubic curves with a base point

Comment: Lines in $\mathbf{P}^1$ are still lines in $\mathbf{P}^1$, whatever affine patch you chose to write them down in. If $y = mx + n$, then $w = -1/y = -1/(m x + n) = -1/(m. z/w + n)$; multiplying through we get $w . (mz/w + n) = -1$ or $mz + nw = -1$ which is clearly still a lline.

Comment: @Mummy the turkey  Thank you, but in Silverman 'Composition Law 2.1', the book reads 'Let E be an elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation'. But I see we can apply the 'geometric group law rule' to every 'smooth cubic curve with a base point'. Edwards curve is not cubic, so we cannot apply it to his curve.

Comment: @bellow Indeed. However, the curve in your question is cubic - so you can just do the chord and tangent process. (I didn't notice the "let $E$ be given by Weierstrass equation" in Silverman - but this is a red herring, see e.g., Cassels "Lectures on Elliptic Curves" p27). You are correct that this doesn't work on the Edwards curve, the group law is induced by the Jacobian (the Edwards curve is not smooth either) - find a birational morphism to a cubic curve, compute the group law there and send it back.

Comment: If you look at the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%5E3%2Bx+y%5E2) you can still use the tangent-chord. Is there a specific reason for this transform?

Comment: @kelalaka This is usual transform to make infinite point to origin.we can see this in Silverman,' the arithmetic of elliptic curves' ,Chapter Ⅳ, formal group.

Comment: @bellow yes, then you have another point at infinity. So what is the gain?

Comment: @kelalaka z has exactly order one at [0:1:0], and you can write ω as the power series of z in this form. This is advantage, and we can introduce formal group associated to elliptic curves.

Comment: E´　has group structure because E　has group structure and there is birational map (which is also isogeny) between Eand E´ ,so E´　has also group structure with origin a group identity. The group law is given by  arithmetically like E´s because this birational map transforms a line to a line. Is my explanation correct？

Comment: @buoyant No. It is **not correct**. You have to take some corrected $E'$, then it works. And this was already mentioned in previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

We divide by $-y^3=(-y)^3$ both sides in $y^2 =x^3-x$.

Then we get
$(-1/y)=(-x/y)^3 \color{red}{-} (-x/y)(-1/y)^2$, so the new curve has the affine equation $w=z^3-zw^2$.

For the homogenized equation,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&E'\ &:\ WT^2&=Z^3-ZW^2\ ,\qquad\text{associated to}\\
&E'_{\text{affine}}\ &:\ w&=z^3-zw^2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
obtained using the correspondence
$w=W/T$, $z=Z/T$,
so that an affine point $(z,w)$ goes to $[Z:W:T]=[z:w:1]$.

There are three points "at infinity" on $E'$ (w.r.t. the chosen affine part), the ones with $T=0$: They are $\Omega_a=[a:1:0]$ with $a$ among $-1$, $0$, $1$.
They correspond to the three points $(a,0)$ on $E$.

We will work in the sequel over $\Bbb Q$.

The line $Z=0$ intersects the curve $E'$ in three points, $O:=[0:0:1]=(0,0)$ with multiplicity one and $\Omega$ with multiplicity two.
This should be considered when writing formulas. Below, i will consider only the "generic case", which is the case when all constructed points involved are $\ne \Omega$.

We will describe the operations which makes *a posteriori* $O\in E'(\Bbb Q)$ to be the neutral element of the group $(E'(\Bbb Q),+)$.

---

Consider two $\Bbb Q$-rational affine points, $P_1=(z_1,w_1)$, $P_2=(z_2,w_2)$.
The equation of the line $P_1P_2$ is then of the shape
$$
(L)\ :\ w = mz+n\ ,
$$
with $m=\displaystyle\frac{w_1-w_2}{z_1-z_2}$, which makes sense for power series purposes around $O=(0,0)$ since $w$ has order $3$, $z$ order $1$ around zero, and unfortunately we will also need
$n=\displaystyle\frac{z_1w_2-z_2w_1}{z_1-z_2}$. In case the two points conicide, $P_1=P_2$, the line has the "same" equation, but $m,n$ are obtained by formally differentiating $(E')$, to get
$$dw =3z^2\; dz-w^2\; dz-2zw\; dw\ .$$
Formally replacing $(z,w)$ by $(z_1,w_1)$, and $dz, dw$ by $(z-z_1)$ and respectively $(w-w_1)$ we obtain the first order Taylor polynomial approximation around $P_1$. This gives $(1+2z_1w_1)\; dw= (3z_1^2-w_1^2)\; dz$. So $\displaystyle m=\frac
{3z_1^2-w_1^2}{1+2z_1w_1}$, which is also fine around $O$. Then set $n$ again so that $w_1=mz_1+n$.

The system with two equations, $(E')$ and $(L)$, in the two unknowns has three solutions, Bezout, we obtain an equation of degree three in $z$ by the linear substitution of $w$ from $(L)$ in $(E')$, thus getting:
$$
0 = z^3-z(mz+n)^2-(mz+n)\ .
$$

- The coefficient in $z^3$ is $1-m^2$.
- The coefficient in $z^2$ is $-2mn$.
- So the third point of intersection $P_3'=(z_3',w_3')$, counted with multiplicities, has the $z$-component delivered by Vieta:
  $$z_3'=-z_1-z_2+\frac{2mn}{1-m^2}\ .$$
- The $w$ component of $P_3'$ is then
  $$w_3'=mz_3'+n\ .$$

Now we consider the line $OR_3'$, which intersects $E'$ in a third point $R_3$. This point is the point we need.
Now note that together with a point $(z,w)$ on $(E')$ the point $(-z,-w)$ is also a point on $(E')$. With this observation we can directly accept the formula for $R_3=(z_3,w_3):=(-z_3',-w_3')$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_3 &=z_1+z_2-\frac{2mn}{1-m^2}\ ,\\
w_3 &=mz_3-n\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

To have some power series experiment, i will use sage, and some point with coordinates in the power series ring $R=\Bbb Q[[ q ]]$. If this feels alien while regarding  the target in the OP, *please ignore the following*. I insert this since some power series application was suggested in the comments.

Investigations on this path have their origin in

[Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, John T. Tate](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Efranz/ta/tate.pdf), §3, Expansion near Zero, The Formal Group.

With a completely different starting point and target, rather for my purposes, there is still some open project in my bottom drawer related to the following experiment, which uses power series coming from the modular parametrization...

I will use [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) in the following.

The addition and multiplication of "blind tuples", corresponding to affine points on the given curve, is implemented as follows.

```
def add(P1, P2):
    z1, w1 = P1
    z2, w2 = P2
    if z1 != z2:
        m = (w1 - w2)/(z1 - z2)
        # and n = (z1*w2 - z2*w1)/(z1 - z2)
    else:
        m = (3*z1^2 - w1^2)/(1 + 2*z1*w1)
    n = w1 - m*z1    # in both cases

    z3 = z1 + z2  - 2*m*n/(1 - m^2)
    w3 = m*z3 - n
    return (z3, w3)

def mul(n, P):
    if n not in ZZ: return None
    if n == 0: return (0,0)
    if n == 1: return P
    if n < 0: 
        z, w = mul(-n, P)
        return (-z, -w)
    if n % 2: 
        return add(P, mul((n-1), P))
    # else n is an even positive integer and we compute
    Q = mul(ZZ(n/2), P)
    return add(Q, Q)
```

Now we can start experimenting.

We may start with $z=q$, and ask for the corresponding lift of $w$ in the power series ring in $q$. Since in our special case $w$ is the solution of the equation of second degree $qw^2+w-q^3=0$, we already have a formula for a starting point.
We will compute some multiples of this point.

```
R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=40)
w = 1/2/q*(-1 + sqrt(1+4*q^4))
P = (q, w)

for n in [1..5]:
    Q = mul(n, P)
    print(f"{n} * P has the components:")
    print('\t', Q[0] + O(q^20))
    print('\t', Q[1] + O(q^20))
```

This gives:

```
1 * P has the components:
     q + O(q^20)
     q^3 - q^7 + 2*q^11 - 5*q^15 + 14*q^19 + O(q^20)
2 * P has the components:
     2*q + 12*q^5 + 44*q^9 + 184*q^13 + 716*q^17 + O(q^20)
     8*q^3 + 16*q^7 + 112*q^11 + 288*q^15 + 1712*q^19 + O(q^20)
3 * P has the components:
     3*q + 96*q^5 + 2432*q^9 + 62976*q^13 + 1628160*q^17 + O(q^20)
     27*q^3 + 405*q^7 + 13014*q^11 + 314793*q^15 + 8325594*q^19 + O(q^20)
4 * P has the components:
     4*q + 408*q^5 + 34136*q^9 + 2904688*q^13 + 247097240*q^17 + O(q^20)
     64*q^3 + 3200*q^7 + 326528*q^11 + 26521856*q^15 + 2285282688*q^19 + O(q^20)
5 * P has the components:
     5*q + 1248*q^5 + 257920*q^9 + 54156800*q^13 + 11371264000*q^17 + O(q^20)
     125*q^3 + 15475*q^7 + 3862810*q^11 + 777959167*q^15 + 165141476790*q^19 + O(q^20)
```

We can check that the above points are on the curve. For instance for the last point...

```
sage: z5, w5 = mul(5, P)
sage: w5 == z5^3 - z5*w5^2
True

sage: z5 + O(q^20)
5*q + 1248*q^5 + 257920*q^9 + 54156800*q^13 + 11371264000*q^17 + O(q^20)
sage: w5 + O(q^20)
125*q^3 + 15475*q^7 + 3862810*q^11 + 777959167*q^15 + 165141476790*q^19 + O(q^20)
```

---

The experiment using power series related to the modular parametrization are of the shape

```
E = EllipticCurve(QQ, [-1, 0])
X, Y = E.modular_parametrization().power_series(40)
R = X.parent()    # power series ring in q truncated with precision 40
R.inject_variables()

print("Modular parametrization of the Fermat curve y² = x³ - x:")
print(f"X = {X}")
print(f"Y = {Y}")
print("\nWe associate Z = -X/Y and W = -1/Y:")
Z, W = -X/Y, -1/Y
print(f"Z = {Z}")
print(f"W = {W}")


print("\n\nThen using the point P = (Z, W):")
P = (Z, W)
for n in [1..5]:
    Q = mul(n, P)
    print(f"{n} * P has the components:")
    print('\t', Q[0] + O(q^20))
    print('\t', Q[1] + O(q^20))
```

This gives:

```
Modular parametrization of the Fermat curve y² = x³ - x:
X = q^-2 + q^2 + q^6 - q^18 - q^22 + q^30 + 2*q^34 + O(q^38)
Y = -q^-3 - q - 2*q^5 - q^9 + 2*q^17 + 2*q^21 + q^25 - q^29 - 4*q^33 + O(q^37)

We associate Z = -X/Y and W = -1/Y:
Z = q - q^9 + 2*q^17 - 3*q^25 + 4*q^33 + O(q^41)
W = q^3 - q^7 - q^11 + 2*q^15 + q^19 - 2*q^23 - 2*q^27 + 2*q^31 + 4*q^35 - 4*q^39 + O(q^43)


Then using the point P = (Z, W):
1 * P has the components:
     q - q^9 + 2*q^17 + O(q^20)
     q^3 - q^7 - q^11 + 2*q^15 + q^19 + O(q^20)
2 * P has the components:
     2*q + 12*q^5 + 42*q^9 + 124*q^13 + 324*q^17 + O(q^20)
     8*q^3 + 16*q^7 + 88*q^11 + 176*q^15 + 552*q^19 + O(q^20)
3 * P has the components:
     3*q + 96*q^5 + 2429*q^9 + 62496*q^13 + 1606278*q^17 + O(q^20)
     27*q^3 + 405*q^7 + 12933*q^11 + 311958*q^15 + 8182683*q^19 + O(q^20)
4 * P has the components:
     4*q + 408*q^5 + 34132*q^9 + 2902648*q^13 + 246790024*q^17 + O(q^20)
     64*q^3 + 3200*q^7 + 326336*q^11 + 26499456*q^15 + 2281691456*q^19 + O(q^20)
5 * P has the components:
     5*q + 1248*q^5 + 257915*q^9 + 54150560*q^13 + 11368942730*q^17 + O(q^20)
     125*q^3 + 15475*q^7 + 3862435*q^11 + 777850842*q^15 + 165098987005*q^19 + O(q^20)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindfull and elaborate answer. 
I have three questions,
                                                                                                                                      1.At the first process, what do we do when y＝0? What is the infinite point of E’ ?
2.P183 of John H.Tate, the author reads z3＝F（z1,z2）has coefficients in Z[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6].But I think this does not hold when character of K is positive. We need to replace Z to Fp. Isn’t it?

Comment: 3. To say the truth, I don’t understand why such transformation gives power series of ω in terms of z, does it have to do with z is a uniformizer? 
Thank you for your great answer.

Comment: For (1): There are three points on $E$ with $y=0$. They are $(-1,0)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$. They are then mapped into points at infinity on $E'$. (I typed that part with a false version of $E'$, the one with the plus sign... After correction of the sign in $E'$ - because the modular parametrization taken from $E$ did not work with the new equation - i missed to edit also that point. Now the answer is corrected, thanks for pointing to this!

Comment: (2) In case we work over the prime field $\Bbb F_p$ (or some extension $K$) the ring $\Bbb Z[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6]$ (and there is no $a_5$) is a subring of $K$, the one generated by $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6$, so $\Bbb Z$ is automatically replaced by $\Bbb F_p$ as a matter of notation.

Comment: (3) Yes, $z$ is a uniformizer, and one computes the coefficients of $w$ as a power series in $z$ so that $w\in z^3+O(z^4)$ one by one inductively. Then for $\omega$, from an expression of the shape $$\omega =dz\cdot\frac{-2z^{-3}+\dots}{-2z^{-3}+\dots}$$ where the two dots stay for different power series with coefficients in the ring $R=\Bbb Z[\frac 12,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6]$. We multiply with $-z^3$ in numerator and denominator in the same time, getting $$\omega =dz\cdot\frac 12\cdot \frac{2+\dots}{1+\dots}$$and denominator is invertible in $R[[z]]$. The same with the other representation.

Comment: I've got some downvote for this answer, which was typed in train and edited locally, it is indeed possible that something very special is wrong there, so please dear downvoter tell me the reason, it is my only chance to improve after the above little work and really get the details right when the road is clear. The first version was typed longer time ago, there was some (sign) correction to be done for the question, and the sage code made it possible to make the things work. I've also inserted a link to an Inventiones paper, showing that despite of the comments, the question has its reason.

Comment: E´　has group structure because E　has group structure and there is birational map (which is also isogeny) between Eand E´ ,so E´　has also group structure with origin a group identity. The group law is given by arithmetically like E´s because this birational map transforms a line to a line. Is my explanation correct？

Comment: @buoyant OK, so the above proposition appears now at three places, as a comment to the OP, as a comment to my answer, and as an own answer. Well, related to the above answer - there is no relation. This answer is here mainly to show that the computation from the equation of $E$, $y^2=x^3-x$, to the other equation, $E'$ from the OP, $w=z^3\color{red}{+}zw^2$, is false, there is a sign error. Then, on the correct(ed) $E'$ there are "two possibilities" to "induce" an addition on $E'(\Bbb Q)$ making $O:=(0,0)$ the neutral element, just like in the OP, given $P,Q$ draw $PQ$, intersect with the...

Comment: @buoyant ... curve, get a point $R'$, draw $R'O$, intersect it with the curve, obtain a point $R$, and this is by definition $P+Q$. This is done explicitly above. In fact, Mummy the turkey already comments (after the OP). And this was also the question, can we do this?! So the short answer to the OP is "Yes, this is the standard way". The "other answer" is to do as in your comments/answer. In fact, Mummy the turkey already comments (after the OP) on this, and your comments/answer reload the path. I am doing above both, using the corrected $E'$ + check on some examples that both paths agree.

Comment: @buoyant Was this the downvote reason? The fact that i have a big digression / deviation from the real question? If so, please note that your answer is also not answering strictly the question: *Does $E'$ : $w=z^3+zw^2$ have group structure, just like <<take two points from $E′$, and line through those points intersects at $E′$, and connect the point with $(0,0)$, then the line intersects with $E′$ again, and this is the sum of first two points>>?* Instead, it prescribes "an other" way to construct an operation. (And - of course - both ways coincide...)

Comment: Thank you for generous comments, but i believe my answer strictly answers the question. It is important that E´　inherits not only the elliptic curveness but also the group structure from E´s arithmetic gloup law.They are isom as avelian variety by the biratinal. We can write down the group law of E´　inherited from E´s arithmeticallyand that is exactly a arithmetic group law which OP writes down. This is normt coincidence.

Comment: Thanks again to the downvoter. What is false in the above answer?

Comment: @buoyant No, it does not answer the question as it stays. It may answer the question "*Does $E'$ : $w=z^3+zw^2$ have group structure?*" - if you use a **corrected** $E$. But it does not answer the question as stated, there is some detail added. "*Does $E'$ : $w=z^3+zw^2$ have group structure*, **just like**... ?" To understand this not so subtle logic of communication, please consider the question: "Can i travel from Paris to Moskow, by just changing train in Budapest?" and compare the answers "Yes, you can", which applies also for the OP, and in your spirit, "Yes, there is a direct flight."

Answer (score 0):

E´　has group structure because E　has group structure and there is birational map (which is also isogeny) between Eand E´ ,　so E´　has also group structure with origin a group identity. The group law is given by arithmetically like E´s because this birational map transforms a line to a line.

Comment: Which is the isogeny between $E$ and $E'$?

Comment: The birational map is also isogeny because it keeps base point.

Comment: Explicitly, the map is [X:Y:Z]→[X:Z:-Y].This is birational and isogeny map from projective closure of E to projective closure of E´.

Comment: So you start with $Y^2Z=X^3-XZ^2$ and now replace $Y$ by $Z$ and $Z$ by $-Y$. This leads to $Z^2(-Y)=X^3-XY^2$. The affine version is $-y=x^3-xy^2$. This is not $E'$. Or you want to replace $Y$ by $-Z$ and $Z$ by $Y$? This leads to $y=x^3-xy^2$. Again not that $E'$ from the OP. What about making the computation explicitly? What about showing how you get from one curve to the other one? To understand the point, just note that the curves $y^2=x^3-x$ and $y^2=x^3+x$ are **not isogenous over** $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: That is just opener´s carelessmistake. I ofcourse know that. You are missing what is importand and what is not. My point of view does not appear in previous commetns, what is important is that the birational is also isogeny, so it is hom as a group, and so it induces group structure to the codomain elliptic curve.

Comment: This is also your mistake now. Just read the given answer.

Comment: Thank　you for your comment.But what do you mean？　In which sentence you mention about isogeny or group hom？

Comment: This is my last comment. You write $E$ and $E'$ are in birational relation. This is **false**. (Or careless, but this is only "because the OP is careless". Well, you are now careless, too.) Then in the comments to the OP Mummy the turkey has a proposition: *find a birational morphism to a cubic curve, compute the group law there and send it back* - it is exactly what you do. I am still not downvoting this. Downvoting means there is an essential error for me. As a final remark, try to use mathjax, thus giving a readable shape to your messages. This is just a form of respect on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your carefull comment. My definition of E´ is different from OP  ´s because you, careful person, corrected that, so i just mentioned the subject. OP may have not realised that the birationa is also group hom(this is not easy to prove from definition), so i answerd. For the last comment, i didn´t downvote your answer. If my memory serves, you were upvoted at once, so at least 2 person but me downvoted your answer. I don´t think your answer is wrong. Thank you for your reapect to ´this site´.